# why cannot the local scope variable be visited in the nested function?

Tags: javascript

```
    <from>
    <input type="number" placeholder="time interval" id="time">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="start">
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <audio src="p.mp3" controls="controls" id="audio">
     Your browser does not support the audio tag.
    </audio>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){
             var music = document.getElementById('audio');
             var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
             //1
             var mytime =  document.getElementById('time').value*60000;
             function musicStart(){
                music.play();
             };
             submit.addEventListener('click',function(){

                //2, var mytime=document.getElementById('time').value*60000;

                 if(music.paused === true){
                    setTimeout(musicStart, mytime);
                    //music.play();
                 }else{
                    //time.value ="";
                    music.pause();
                 }
              })
        }());
    </script>
```

the script as above, when I put the code `var mytime =  document.getElementById('time').value*60000;` in the 1 place, it cannot function but function in the 2 place?

the `mytime` variable (which defined in the `function(){}`) should be visited in the nested function (which is defined in the nested function which is).

why does it not function when i put the mytime variable in the 1 place? help?

Comment: When you put it above the click event, it gets the initial value of the time input (which is empty).  If you put it in the click, it gets the value of the input at the time you do the click

Comment: Thanks very much.I get it

Answer (score 4):

When you load the page, it runs the script at which time the "time" input is empty, so the value of `mytime` will be empty.

When you place it inside the click event, when you run the click, it only then fetches the value, which will give you the result.

Comment: Thanks very much.Great explantion too

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the variable in the parent function, then initialize it inside the nested function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){
             var music = document.getElementById('audio');
             var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
             var mytime;

             function musicStart(){ music.play(); };
             submit.addEventListener('click',function(){

                mytime=document.getElementById('time').value*60000;

                 if(music.paused === true){
                    setTimeout(musicStart, mytime);
                    //music.play();
                 }else{
                    //time.value ="";
                    music.pause();
                 }
              })
        }());
    </script>
```

Comment: there is no need for `mytime` to be on that scope, also this does not answer the OP.

Comment: as pete and Josh Harington have said,  it's the reason of the empty  "time" input when i first load the page, thanks for yr explanation too ,appreciate that. First i thought maybe i have something wrong with my understanding of the javascript function scope, it turns out i am wrong.